# Output in console shows unicode

Tags: unicode, console, rstudio, settings

How can i get my output in the console of in R (Studio) show a normal multiplication sign (x) instead of unicode? an example:

```
> A tibble: 6 <U+00D7> 4
```

I'm working on a mac with R Studio Version 1.0.143.  and R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06). When typing:  `library(tidyverse)` and then `table1` this last object belongs the package, but also when i create a tibble myself i get the same unicode in output. I tried different (reopen with) encoding, But this does not affect the console output.

Comment: How did you get this result ?

Comment: On a mac with R Studio Version 1.0.143.

Comment: Please [edit] the Q and share `Sys.getlocale("LC_ALL")` output.

Comment: Hi, i ran `Sys.getlocale("LC_ALL")`, but only got this as output: `[1] "C"`.